# AMD driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Recently I've installed [Radeon RX Vega Series](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux) driver on Ubuntu 18.04. My system has Ryzen 5 2400g APU with radeon vega 11. After installing this driver, video files are not opened in any video player. If this is wrong driver, then what's the correct driver for this APU? And is it true that AMD users don't like Ubuntu for these kind of graphics problems?

Answer (score 1):

from last week, am also experienced that problem,   AMD graphics drivers not available in ubuntu 18.04 LTS(Bionic bever), But In ubuntu 18.10(Cosmic cuttlefish) have the support of AMD vega series drivers, here the release notes, [New features in 18.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes) at the first line they mention that information